# Nvidia HDMI sound is not working, cant update ALSA driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, alsa, hdmi

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my desktop PC. My graphics Card is 780GTX, it is recognized and works. I updated to the 361 nvidia binaries driver. But the sound over HDMI doesnt work.

The device is connected and it is shown:

```
lspci | grep NVIDIA

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK110 [GeForce GTX 780] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK110 HDMI Audio (rev a1)
```

But its not detected as an output device:

```
aplay -l

Karte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], Gerät 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
```

There is only the Mainboard analog output. I googled a lot. First I tried to disable the mainboard output in UEFI, but nothing changes. Then there are no devices listet in aplay -l. It seems that the device is there but ALSA doesnt recognize it.

I tried to update ALSA with: sudo apt-get install oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms

But the last lines are everytime:

```
 Error configuring:
      oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am not really a ubuntu GURU and hope you can help me. I hope, if the ALSA drivers are updated it will work, so I hope you can assist me to figure out the error.

Could it be that the daily build of the drivers is broken at the moment for 16.04???

ALSA drivers here:
https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/+packages

Comment: >Could it be that the daily build of the drivers is broken at the moment for 16.04??? -- Yes. You should ask there

Answer (score 0):

it was true... The package build for 16.04 was corrupt. Now, 4 days later, updating the ALSA drivers work! Unfortunately it doesnt resolve my issue with my sound over hdmi with my nvidia gtx780...

Best regards,